# Invoke Cordova callback from remote process

Tags: android, cordova, callback, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to invoke a javascript callback with cordova from a remote process?

Plugin.xml:

```
<service android:name="MyLocationListeningService" android:process=":remote" />
```

MyLocationService.java:

```
public MyLocationListeningService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //invoke a javascript callback with cordova
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found my own answer.  No you cannot invoke a javascript callback with Cordova from a remote process.  To invoke a callback you'll need to keep the [CallbackContext](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CallbackContext.java).  The CallbackContext is only provided via [CordovaPlugin.execute](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaPlugin.java) which is only invoked on the "main" application process (i.e. the process the webview runs in).

However, you can communicate between Processes in native android code.  So you can invoke a callback on the original process as prompted by a remote process.

There are many ways to communicate between processes in Android.  One is to broadcast an action for a receiver that runs in the original process.

AndroidMaifest.xml

```
<service android:name="MyLocationListeningService" android:process=":remote" />
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:label="MyReceiver" android:name="my.package.MyReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="Success" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Plugin

```
public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

  public static CallbackContext myCallbackContext;

  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, final CallbackContext callbackContext) {

    if ("SaveCallbackContext".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
      myCallbackContext = callbackContext;
      //Note: we must return true so Cordova doesn't invoke the error
      //callback from the provided callbackContext.
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Receiver (executed in same process as plugin)

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ("Success".equals(intent.getAction()) {
      MyPlugin.callbackContext.success();
    }
  }

}
```

Services (executed in different process from plugin)

```
public MyLocationListeningService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
        i.setAction("Success");
        this.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

*Note: This answer doesn't account for the case when the original process has been terminated.*

*Also, you may be interested in [Keep callback context in PhoneGap plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758756/keep-callback-context-in-phonegap-plugin) if you want to invoke your callback more than once.*

*And you'll be interested in http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins if your callback effects the UI.*